# glyphicons not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

the bootstrap glyphicons I am using in my application only work on safari and not on chrome or firefox. The images of the glyphicons are given below.

[image]

[image]

I am using cloudfront to host all the static content. 
I posted a similar question before and the answer pointed out that the configurations on CDN might be the problem since it was working perfectly fine on development. The changes I made to the CDN are given below.

The answer mentioned to whitelist the production environments host name. I clicked on "distribution", "distribution setting" and "behavior" tab and I clicked on "Edit".
I changed the “Forward Headers,” from “None (Improves Caching)” to “Whitelist.” A “Whitelist Headers” section will appears and I added "host" to the list. This was the only place where I could "whitelist" the host name. I am not exactly sure if I did this correctly.

It still did not work on chrome. I tried using firefox to see if chrome was the problem but it's not working on firefox either. It only works on safari.

I have also set  `config.serve_static_files = true` in the production environment.

As I mentioned, I have posted a similar question earlier but no solution. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**After viewing the chrome console, I see the following errors.**

```
https://d24b01zeuxnthb.cloudfront.net/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings…gular-bd18efd3efd70fec8ad09611a20cdbf99440b2c1d40085c29be036f891d65358.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://d24b01zeuxnthb.cloudfront.net/assets/sprites/social-share-button@2x-a597120b30fe6ae4ac5b4f0f45f307c0f5519851529b3010a7c584eb3ed186be.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Font from origin 'https://xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://scorecliq.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Have you check Chrome developer tools console to see if there is an error related to the load of the resource?

Comment: You might have 2 different issues, but I would suggest taking a quick peek at AWS Cloudfront Forward Header Caching Conflicts at:
    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html
    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-rtmp

There's also a possibility that you might need to Whitelist the reference to the CDN in your Dev environment, as well.  I always look at the code in the rendered browser version to make sure the reference to the file is correct.

Comment: @MarceloMartins, I will update my question with the errors I get from viewing the chrome console.

Comment: *"I am using cloudfront to host all the static content."*  This can't possibly be accurate.  CloudFront does not "host" any content.  The content is hosted on an origin server, *behind* CloudFront, and the logs of that server (which I don't believe you've mentioned, here) are what you need to be reading.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, My terminology wasn't completely accurate, yes my static content is hosted on my origin server which gets cached by cloud front so it can serve future requests. Thanks for pointing that out eventhough it offered no help.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried accessing both the .tff and I've got a 404. The same doesn't happen to the .png.  So check to make sure the .tff file has been committed to Prod. But this is an issue caused by HTTPS cross-domain resource references that could be mitigated if the sources would use the same TLD and a wild SSL certificate.  As you know, the same doesn't happen in an HTTP app with HTTPS resources.

While the CDN has the convenience to decrease app resources & load time it does come with some caveats, too. In this case, you will need to drop the CDN to avoid the cross domain issues and move the glyphicons fonts to the project. This will resolve the issues you are having in any environment as long as all the files are committed and released properly.